# How can I find in SQL for a match of 15 characters out of 17?

Tags: sql, string, full-text-search

I have a table where a field is varchar(17) and contains 17 char long phrases. They are alphanumeric. I need to add another row this table, but before I do, I need to check for possible duplicates. The logic for duplicates needs to be if any 15 characters of the new phrase matches with any 15 characters to a record in the table.

```
Samples:
5 Table rows:

1N6BF0KM2HN802620
1N6BF0KMXHN801974
1N6BF0LYXHN811101
1N9BF0KM6HN800482
1N12F0LY4HN809375

New phrase to add: 1N6BF0KAXHN802974
Found in table row 2: 1N6BF0KMXHN801974
Duplicate: Does not match 2 charaters only

New phrase to add: 109BF0KM6HN800492
Found in table row 4: 1N9BF0KM6HN800482
Duplicate: Does not match 2 charaters only

New phrase to add: 1N12F0LY4HN709375
Found in table row 5: 1N12F0LY4HN809375
Not Duplicate: Does not match 1 charaters

New phrase to add: 1N6AF0BYXHN911101
Found in table row 3: 1N6BF0LYXHN811101
Not Duplicate: Does not match more than 2 charaters
```

I try searching for regular expression or any algorism.

Comment: I don't think this can be done without matching thousands of patterns. You need 2^17 patterns with wildcards in every pair of positions.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is to see other ways. Maybe using regex and returning the difference of the 2 strings? I'm not so good with regular expressions. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using

- a function which compares a pair of string character by character and returns the number of matches
- which uses the function to compare a string with all the values already in the table before entering it.

I don't think that regex is appropriate because we would need to count the number of matches with different regex pattern fir each existing entry. Regex is good for matching to a pattern which doesn't change.

> ```
> create table sample (Samples char(17));
> insert into sample values
> ('1N6BF0KM2HN802620'),
> ('1N6BF0KMXHN801974'),
> ('1N6BF0LYXHN811101'),
> ('1N9BF0KM6HN800482'),
> ('1N12F0LY4HN809375');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.countMatches
> (
> @string1 CHAR(17) ,
> @string2 CHAR(17)
> )
> returns int
> AS
> BEGIN
>      DECLARE @IsMatching int =0 ;
>      DECLARE @loopCount INT = 0;
>      SET @IsMatching = 0;
>      WHILE @loopCount < 17
>         BEGIN
>              IF( 
>                 SUBSTRING(@string1,@loopCount+1,1)
>                 = SUBSTRING(@string2,@loopCount+1,1) 
>                 )
>               BEGIN
>                 SET @IsMatching = @IsMatching + 1;
>               END;
>             SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1;
>         END   
> RETURN @IsMatching
> END
> ```

> ```
> create procedure insertSample (@newSample char(17))
> as
> begin
> DECLARE @sample char(17);
> declare @IsMatching int;
> declare @thisMatching int = 0;
> DECLARE sample_Cursor CURSOR 
>    FOR SELECT samples FROM sample
> OPEN sample_Cursor 
>
> FETCH NEXT FROM sample_Cursor INTO @sample
>
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
> BEGIN
>     set @IsMatching=dbo.countMatches(
>         @sample, @newSample);
>     FETCH NEXT FROM sample_Cursor INTO @sample
>     if (@IsMatching > @thisMatching)
>     begin
>       set @thisMatching = @IsMatching;
>     end
> END
> CLOSE sample_Cursor
> DEALLOCATE sample_Cursor
>   if (@thisMatching >  14) 
>     RAISERROR (
>        'too many matching characters',16, 1)
>     else
>     begin
>       insert into sample values(@newSample);
>       select 'ok accepted' result,
>          @thisMatching numMatches;
>      end
>   RETURN;
> end
> ```

> ```
> EXEC insertSample '1N6BF0KAXHN802974'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 50000 Level 16 State 1 Line 26
> ```

too many matching characters

> 

> ```
> EXEC insertSample '109BF0KM6HN800492'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 50000 Level 16 State 1 Line 26
> ```

too many matching characters

> 

> ```
> EXEC insertSample '1N12F0LY4HN709375'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 50000 Level 16 State 1 Line 26
> ```

too many matching characters

> 

> ```
> EXEC insertSample '1N6AF0BYXHN911101'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> result      | numMatches
> :---------- | ---------:
> ok accepted |         14
> ```

> ```
> select * from sample;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Samples           |
> | :---------------- |
> | 1N6BF0KM2HN802620 |
> | 1N6BF0KMXHN801974 |
> | 1N6BF0LYXHN811101 |
> | 1N9BF0KM6HN800482 |
> | 1N12F0LY4HN809375 |
> | 1N6AF0BYXHN911101 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT dbo.countMatches(
>           '1N12F0LY4HN709375',
>           '1N12F0LY4HN709366');
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |               15 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2916d41548afce41ba6a3953a460bb19)*

Comment: Wouldn't a function be more useful for this, so you can compare the result in a join condition?

Comment: Kendle, thanks for the idea. Its a lot less than 2^17 combination search I first thought of, but like I mention above, maybe using regex may be faster? I don't know how to set this scenario using regex. Anyone?